# Flutter WebSocket works in web application but not in android emulator

Tags: flutter, dart, web, emulation

'final channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
Uri.parse('wss://echo.websocket.org'),
);'

1. can create and connect in web application
   but can't connect in android emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In my project WebSocket connection needs authentication
2. In web application automatically pass cookies and authentication token in
   websocket connection
3. But in Mobile Application we need to set cookies and authentication
   token manually

When I done this resolved my issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are two libraries implementing WebSocket class - one that works on web, the other on Andoroid.

You can sort this out by creating a simple factory function. You will need to create several files:

**websocket_client_factory.dart**

```
export 'websocket_client_factory_null.dart'
    if (dart.library.html) 'websocket_client_factory_web.dart'
    if (dart.library.io) 'websocket_client_factory_server.dart';
```

**websocket_client_factory_null.dart**

```
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

WebSocketChannel makeWsClient(String url) {
  throw 'Platform not supported';
}
```

**websocket_client_factory_server.dart**

```
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

WebSocketChannel makeWsClient(String url) =>
    IOWebSocketChannel.connect(url, protocols: ['graphql-ws']);
```

**websocket_client_factory_web.dart**

```
import 'package:web_socket_channel/html.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

WebSocketChannel makeWsClient(String url) =>
    HtmlWebSocketChannel.connect(url, protocols: ['graphql-ws']);
```

Now, from your original file just import the factory file, and call the factory function:

```
import 'package:./websocket_client_factory.dart';

...
var channel = makeWsClient(wssUrl);
```